# What is the best option for public transportation in Rome, in terms of cost and public transport coverage?

Tags: public-transport, budget, tickets, rome, atac

I am going to Rome in 40 hours, and I need to know what the best option for the public transportation is.

I know that in Rome there are just two main metro lines (actually three, but the last one doesn't go to tourist places), so the main transportation is bus. I also read that there is a daily ticket (but I don’t know if it works with both bus and trams and metros). I know that there is a three-day ticket (but 36 euros :( ).

I'll be visiting the main tourist places. I will be there from February 16 after noon until February 20 after noon, for a total of 4 days.

Could you help me select the best public transportation card please? By best I mean the cheapest option that will allow me to travel on most types of public transportation.

I don't know if the three-day ticket is good or a day for each trip is good because I read that if I buy one ticket, it will be available to work for 1 hour.

Comment: @JoErNanO I think the 1.5 EUR standard ticket is valid for 100 minutes from Stamp Validation, & allow one metro (as long as you stay inside turnstiles) & related bus/road transport journey, provided everything is between this 100 minutes.

Comment: @JoErNanO Sorry, I mis-understood "journey" as one single direct travel from A to B, whereas actually it means A to D via possible B and/or C. I stand corrected.

Comment: @JoErNanO No need, its just that I, as a non-native english user, misinterpreted "journey" as "direct-journey". Now that you have explained, its clear. If you want, please add that "All Bus/Tram transport within 100 minutes allowed", after the bit "once you exit the metro".

Comment: The 100-minutes BIT ticket can be used only once on the metro. In other words, once you exit the metro you'll have to purchase another ticket if you want to travel by metro again, regardless how much time you have left on the first ticket. However, you can still use the ticket on over-ground transportation (buses, trams, etc.) until the 100-minutes expire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Count your Metro Trips

The only metric I would use when budgeting public transportation costs in Rome is the number of metro journeys you think you'll travel per day. The reason is simple: [**a 100-minute BIT ticket can only be used for a single metro trip**](http://www.atac.roma.it/page.asp?p=229). In other words, if you exit the metro and still have some time to spare on the ticket, you won't be allowed to use it again on another metro trip.

The Roma 24-hour ticket costs 4.67 times as much as a BIT ticket, and allows you to travel on unlimited journeys for the 24 hours following its validation. If you think you'll be taking the metro 5 or more times per day, then I'd suggest this ticket over 5 single BIT tickets, since you'd be saving money.

Similarly, the Roma 48-hour ticket costs 8.33 times as much as a BIT ticket, and allows you to travel on unlimited journeys for the 48 hours following its validation. If you think you'll be taking the metro 9 or more times in two days, then I'd suggest this ticket over 9 single BIT tickets.

Finally, the Roma 72-hour ticket costs 12 times as much as a BIT ticket, and allows you to travel on unlimited journeys for the 72 hours following its validation. If you think you'll be taking the metro 12 or more times in three days, then I'd suggest this ticket over 12 single BIT tickets.

Frankly, most of the times I just stick with BIT tickets, since I usually only need 2 metro trips per day. Moreover, you'll probably be walking more than you'll be taking public transport, once you get to your designed tourist area.

Comment: +1 Cant stress enough *"you'll probably be walking more than you'll be taking public transport, once you get to your designed tourist area."*

Answer (score 4):

*Source for all these: [Official Site, Tickets & Passes http://www.atac.roma.it/page.asp?p=229](http://www.atac.roma.it/page.asp?p=229) Click the links/labels for information on this page, but the URL does not change everytime, so I could not link to each section directy.*

Almost all of the Rome can be traversed by foot for tourism purposes, with an occasional one-use transport ticket EUR 1.50, but it needs careful planning, as **Machines do not dispense any change mote that 4 EUR, you insert a note for which the machine isn't able to dispense change, then that note will be spat out by the machine** *(for more see comment by [joernano](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) in comments)*, or are out-of-work (mostly).

Also there is a time-limit on these tickets(100 Minutes). It means that you are allowed to change as many metros or stops as long as you stay inside the turnstiles, & unlimited bus/tram transport, as long as all this is within 100 minutes of Stamp Validation.

Careful, as any time you used up for waiting the metro @ Platform will also be counted in this as many stations have Validation Stamp m/cs at station entrance, & platforms are either on other level, or not-in-direct-sight. The fines for travelling with no-ticket/expired-ticket/non-validated ticket is Minimum EUR 100, which will be reduced to EUR 50 if paid within 5 days.

Quote:

> Valid for100 minutes from first validation; just for a single journey on metro/train urban route, even using different lines, but without passing through the turnstiles.

The most convenient/no-nonsense option will be [CIS WEEKLY INTEGRATED TICKET](http://www.atac.roma.it/page.asp?p=229) a 7 Calendar Days weekly Ticket, valid from the date of first validation, to the 23:59:59 of 7th Calendar day, for the price of EUR 24.

Quote:

> Valid until midnight of the  seventh day including the day of validation, for unlimited journeys within the city of  Rome.

Also, 72 Hours / Three Day Transport Ticket (not Museums/Attraction Pass) is not EUR 36, but only EUR 18, valid for only/all public transport within the Rome City (Some Circle, last stations are marked by red on Official Transport Map http://www.atac.roma.it/files/doc.asp?r=385

Quote:

> 72 Hour Ticket - valid for unlimited metro, bus, and train travel within Rome for 72 hours from validation. € 18.00

There are packs of 10 Tickets at discounted price (Offline/Paper based, multiple tickets can be used at same time, if multiple passengers. Online version is tied to one person, & can not be shared.

All these above works with any kind of Public Transport (in Rome City only, both Airports not covered). Not all tickets are available online, but all are available on Machines , Tobacco Shops.

*I will also be in Rome for 9 days coming month.*

Various Maps at same website http://www.atac.roma.it/page.asp?p=18

Comment: Ticket machines aren't that bad. Although it's worth mentioning that sometimes they have no change. The real problem is that the maximum change you can get from a machine is 4EUR. Hence, *bring coins*.

Comment: :) yup, I did not remember 4 EUR limit. Machines do not dispense complete change most of the time. Will update answer.

Comment: Put the 4 EUR limit in bold capital italics. :) Also, remind readers that if you insert a note for which the machine isn't able to dispense change, then that note *will be spat out* by the machine. If the note stays inside, call an attendant without leaving the machine. There's been an increase of frauds in which people deliberately block the note from being spat out, and proceed to release the note once the machine is left unattended.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get the 4 euro thing, do you mean that If I put 5 euro in the machine, it will not return the 4 euro to me ?

Comment: @JoErNanO the same comments if you know the answer please

Comment: @sarah No. The machine *cannot*, give more than 4EUR back. So if you try to pay 8EUR with a 20EUR banknote it won't work, since the change would be 12EUR, **and the machine should give you the banknote back**.

Comment: @JoErNanO OMG, what a crazy thing? it sounds like a popular problem and yet they didn't solve it ???!!!, anyway, what do I do with this banknote please? (and is the banknote a paper) ?

Comment: @sarah the only option is use coin/bank-notes of total not more that your ticket price + 4 EUR. e.g. For a ticket of 1.5EUR, Use only a combination of maximum 5.5. For a ticket of 10 EUR, use maximum 14 EUR.

Comment: @sarah Tickets can also be purchased at newsagent stands and tobacco shops (marked with a big T outside of the shop). Newsagent stands are ubiquitous, and sometimes can be found inside the metro station, especially in busy touristic ones.